# Scala: Variables containing types

Tags: scala, reflection

How would I write use a variable as a type? For example:

```
scala> class A
defined class A

scala> class B extends A
defined class B

scala> def convert[F, T](from: F): T = from.asInstanceOf[T]
convert: [F, T](from: F)T

scala> val b = new B
b: B = B@54038f36

scala> convert[B, A](b)
res18: A = B@54038f36
```

This works fine. But I am interested in doing:

```
scala> val aType = classOf[A]
aType: Class[A] = class A

scala> convert[B, aType](b)
<console>:12: error: not found: type aType
              convert[B, aType](b)
```

How would I do this without initializing an object and using `obj.type` in there? I suspect that I need to use some reflection features (maybe `TypeTag`?), but I couldn't find out what the correct thing to use here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java's `Class` has a method `cast` which does exactly what you need:

```
val aType = classOf[A]
aType.cast(b)
```

Now as a method:

```
def convert[F,T](from: F, clazz: Class[T]) = clazz.cast(from)
```

And call:

```
convert(b, aType)
```

Comment: Why do I keep on not seeing these... Thanks very much!